# iPad UISplitViewController with multiple views

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Lets say I have a basic iPad UISplitViewController. Now lets say in the RootViewController I have 3 rows: "Row 1", "Row 2" and "Row 3". And lets say I also have three classes, Class_1_Controller, Class_2_Controller and Class_3_Controller, each with their respective .xib. I want to set up the UISplitViewController so that when I select a row in the RootViewController, it displays the appropriate .xib.  I've looked at Apple sample code and all over the web and I'm still having difficulties.  Can anyone point me in the right direction, or give me advise/sample code. anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you see the Multiple detail view sample [code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html) ?

Comment: yes. I've seen that thanks.  I got it working after a little while of playing around with it.